# Problem programmatically accessing the iTunes library 

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator, ipod-touch

I built an app that must access the iTunes library. I used MPMediaQuer to retrieve songs from the library as in the following.

```
MPMediaQuery *media = [[MPMediaQuery alloc]init];
NSArray *arr = [media items];

for(MPMediaItem *song in arr)
{
    //To print songs title
    NSString *title = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    NSLog(@"%@", title);
}
```

But nothing printed!

And I tried to print the count of the `arr` array and the result is 0 as in the following.

```
NSLog(@"%D",[arr count]);
```

And I'm sure there are some songs in the iTunes Library.

Do this problem occur because I test in the simulator? And if I test the code on device should it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iPod Library Access APIs [only works on devices](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008765-CH1-SW1), that's why you aren't getting any result on the iPhone Simulator:

> Note: iPod library access works only
>   on devices and not in the Simulator.
>   This is because the Simulator has no
>   access to a device’s iPod library. To
>   develop applications using the classes
>   in this technology, you need a
>   provisioned iOS device.

Comment: hay Julio ..Thanks alot for reply as i read this code just must be tested on device.. but from my code..do you expect that when i test on device will work!! i don't have one :( just in this stage i need to print the titles..Do this code ture??

Comment: I'm positive that the code you posted would work on a device as it is.