# iPhone get videos from iPod application

Tags: ios, video

I'm looking for any way to get videos from iPod folder. I looked to AVFoundation framework, but dont see API which allows to do it?

Please help if somebody know solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>[Accessing Videos in library using AssestsLibrary framework iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948485/accessing-videos-in-library-using-assestslibrary-framework-iphone)</strike>

Sorry, here is the Apple documentation on MediaQuery

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008765-CH1-SW1

Here is the note from Documentation.

> Note: iPod library access applies only
>   to audio-based media items. You cannot
>   play video podcasts, movies, or
>   television shows from the iPod
>   library.

[Problem programmatically accessing the iTunes library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484731/programatically-accessing-itunes-library-problem)

Comment: Thank you, but this API avails to get videos/photos from Photos application folder, but not from iPod folder.